# statEt troubleshooting

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I have downloaded R and statET to run R through eclipse, additionally, I have the 'rj' package downloaded, but when I try to launch R through eclipse, I get this error message. I suspect that my 'rj' package is in the wrong spot, but I don't know what the right spot is.

```
Launching the R Console was cancelled, because it seems starting the R engine failed.

Please make sure that R package 'rj' (2.1 or compatible) is installed and that the R library paths are set correctly for the R environment configuration 'R-3.4.3'.
```

What is the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

there are several links on the statet page, what version of statet are you running ? From your message I guess you are running `Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)`.

On the statet download page you can find the following [table](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet).

[image]

So you need to install this using the following command.

**For RJ 2.1 (StatET 3.6):**

> install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"),repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.1")

In addition, if you are in windows when installing package often you download them in a directory where you have the right in non administrator mode e.g. ‘C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/. This does not work. You need to run the install command with full administrator rights.

Comment: If that still does not work post a comment I'll try to help you.

Comment: please confirm your eclipse/ R / versions `sessionInfo()`